# meaning of the word "heave" in context?

Tags: meaning

It is from a [video](https://youtu.be/nn8YGPZdCvA) of the the YouTube channel TED-ed. Here it goes:

> He galloped through his home in a frenzy, handling each item until it took on a lustrous sheen. Soon the palace **heaved** with gold.

I have cheched all the meanings of *heave*, but It seems to me none fit there.

Comment: It's a metaphor, expressing the idea that there was so much gold that it *spilled over* everywhere. Metaphors employ verbs that generally cannot be interpreted literally.  http://examples.yourdictionary.com/metaphor-examples-for-kids.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb **heave**, when used intransitively as in the animation about Midas, means to rise up  forming a mound, or to become swollen.

See [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=4tMaCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT166&dq=%22heaved%20with%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjm4YzFsNjZAhWIl-AKHdQDCfcQ6AEIhQEwEQ#v=onepage&q=%22heaved%20with%22&f=false), for example.

One could also understand it figuratively as the palace **swelled** with gold as a river might swell with rain.  You will sometimes see phrases like "the streets heaved with pedestrians" or "the wagon heaved with hay".

Answer (score 0):

I too hear it as "heave".  This is an odd use of the term, and possibly archaic from when the source the narrator is reading from was written.

My best guess is that it relates to the effort to move a heavy load, as if the palace was so full of gold that the walls were straining to contain it -- but this is not something I would use in any other context.  Even taken metaphorically, it feels clumsy, as there are better verbs to evoke the same image.